# Black-Scholes N(d1) and N(-d1)

Tags: stochastic-calculus

I think my question is how can I calculate N(-d1) if I know N(d1)? I got a question (with solution):

[image]

So I know how to calculate the value of the call, but how should I get the value of N(-d1) or N(-d2) given the value of N(d1) or N(d2)?

Comment: Why do you need $N(-d_1)$?  For a European put you can just get the call price and then use Put Call Parity.

Comment: Standard normal distribution is symmetric so $N(x)+N(-x)=1$.